# French spacing without babel or polyglossia

Tags: spacing, punctuation, languages

To re-edit a document in a constructed language (*latino sine flexione*), I need "French" punctuation spacing **without side effects**.

More specifically, I want a small non-breaking space before any double punctuation marks -- `: ; ! ?` -- and a regular non-breaking space after an opening or before a closing quotation mark (guillemet) -- `«` and `»`.

Comment: Which TeX engine do you employ to compile your document: pdf(La)TeX, Xe(La)TeX, or Lua(La)TeX? And, do please tell us how the guillemets -- `«` and `»` -- are entered: directly as such, or via some macro?

Comment: I currently use `pdflatex`. It doesn't matter about the quotation marks, I will adapt my input to the solution.

Comment: Are you willing to switch to LuaLaTeX?

Comment: I don't mind changing compiler.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "without side effects". I had interpreted this requirement as precluding making the characters `:`, `;`, etc active, since that's exactly what `babel` and `polyglossia` do *and* you had stipulated "without babel or polyglossia" in the title of your posting. In view of the fact that you've accepted a solution that employs the babel&polyglossia approach, which I thought you had ruled out, my interpretation of your requirement was evidently off-base. It would be quite helpful if you explained what the condition "without side effects" is actually supposed to mean.

Comment: It is supposed to mean not changing anything else that punctuation e.g. translating names or modify hyphenation

Comment: It would have been rather helpful if you had spelled this out up front.

Comment: I thought it was clear enough

Comment: Your solution is working, I don’t see any good reason ho delete it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `pdflatex` you can use solution based on changing category code of characters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% saving original quotes representation
\let\gll\guillemotleft
\let\glr\guillemotright
% new quotes representation
\def\frenchguillemotleft{\gll~}
\def\frenchguillemotright{~\glr}
{
    \catcode`\:=\active
    \catcode`\;=\active
    \catcode`\?=\active
    \catcode`\!=\active
    \gdef\frenchpunct{%
        \catcode`\:=\active \def:{\thinspace\char`\: }
        \catcode`\;=\active \def;{\thinspace\char`\; }
        \catcode`\?=\active \def?{\thinspace\char`\? }
        \catcode`\!=\active \def!{\thinspace\char`\! }
        \let\guillemotleft\frenchguillemotleft
        \let\guillemotright\frenchguillemotright
    }
}
\def\nofrenchpunct{%
    \catcode`\:=12
    \catcode`\;=12
    \catcode`\?=12
    \catcode`\!=12
    \let\guillemotleft\gll
    \let\guillemotright\glr
}
\begin{document}
french: french; french? french!
«french»

\frenchpunct
french: french; french? french!
«french»

\nofrenchpunct
french: french; french? french!
«french»
\end{document}
```

[image]

Command `\frenchpunct` make characters `:`, `;`, `?` and `!` active and then define them according to desired behaviour: unbreakable thin space before character. Also this command redefine commands `\guillemotleft` and `\guillemotright` those are declared by `inputenc` package.

Command `\nofrencpunct` change all back.

**Remark:** the above `\frenchpunct` command is local. Therefore being enclosed by groping characters `{}` it take off its effect after leaving group. If you need global command that is canceled only by `\nofrenchpunct` add `\global` before all `\def` (or use `\gdef` that is alias for `\global\def`), `\catcode` and `\let` in `\frenchpunct` definition:

```
\gdef\frenchpunct{%
    \global\catcode`\:=\active \gdef:{\thinspace\char`\: }
    \global\catcode`\;=\active \gdef;{\thinspace\char`\; }
    \global\catcode`\?=\active \gdef?{\thinspace\char`\? }
    \global\catcode`\!=\active \gdef!{\thinspace\char`\! }
    \global\let\guillemotleft\frenchguillemotleft
    \global\let\guillemotright\frenchguillemotright
}
```

And make same for `\nofrenchpunct`:

```
\def\nofrenchpunct{%
    \global\catcode`\:=12
    \global\catcode`\;=12
    \global\catcode`\?=12
    \global\catcode`\!=12
    \global\let\guillemotleft\gll
    \global\let\guillemotright\glr
}
```

Comment: In case the tex input file already contains whitespace *before* `:`, `;`, `!`, `?`, and `»` or *after* `«`, you may want to insert an `\unskip` directive before `\thinspace` and change the definitions of `\frenchguillemotleft` and `\frenchguillemotlright` to include `\ignorespaces` and `\unskip` directives, respectively.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It consists of a Lua function called `french_punctuation_spacing` that does all of the work and two LaTeX utility macros called `\FrenchPunctuationSpacingOn` and `\FrenchPunctuationSpacingOff`, respectively, which activate and deactivate the  Lua function.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}  % for 'luacode' environment
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function french_punctuation_spacing ( s )
  s = s:gsub ( "[:;!?]" , "\\,%0" )
  s = s:gsub ( "«" , "«~" )
  s = s:gsub ( "»" , "~»" )
  return s
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
\newcommand\FrenchPunctuationSpacingOn{\directlua{%
  luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer",
  french_punctuation_spacing , "frenchpunctuationspacing" )}}
\newcommand\FrenchPunctuationSpacingOff{\directlua{%
  luatexbase.remove_from_callback ( "process_input_buffer",
  "frenchpunctuationspacing" )}}

%\usepackage{fontspec} % optional

\begin{document}
bonjour: monde; oui? non! «aujourd'hui»

\FrenchPunctuationSpacingOn % activate the Lua function
bonjour: monde; oui? non! «aujourd'hui»

\FrenchPunctuationSpacingOff % deactivate the Lua function
bonjour: monde; oui? non! «aujourd'hui»
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting solution! I definitely upvoted it.