# French spacing in plain tex / optex

Tags: punctuation, plain-tex, french, optex

I've seen the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526841/french-spacing-without-babel-or-polyglossia) for Latex. How can I adapt this to plain TeX or OPTeX?

```
\frlang
\fontfam[Times]


{
    \catcode`\:=\active
    \catcode`\;=\active
    \catcode`\?=\active
    \catcode`\!=\active 
\catcode`\«=\active 
\catcode`\»=\active 
    \gdef\frenchpunct{%
        \catcode`\:=\active \def:{\thinspace\char`\: }
        \catcode`\;=\active \def;{\thinspace\char`\; }
        \catcode`\?=\active \def?{\thinspace\char`\? }
        \catcode`\!=\active \def!{\thinspace\char`\! }
\catcode`\«=\active \def«{\thinspace\char`\« }
\catcode`\»=\active \def»{\thinspace\char`\» }
    }
}
\def\nofrenchpunct{%
    \catcode`\:=12
    \catcode`\;=12
    \catcode`\?=12
    \catcode`\!=12
\catcode`\«=12
\catcode`\»=12 
}


\frenchpunct
bonjour: monde; oui? non! «aujourd'hui» % opening « does not work, but closing -- » -- does.

\nofrenchpunct

bonjour: monde; oui? non! «aujourd'hui»

\bye
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be ```\catcode\`«=\active \def«{\char\`«\thinspace }``` ? I guess you'd want the thin space to be *after* the opening quotation mark (guillemet).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're almost there, but the space should go *after* the opening guillemet.

I add also `\unskip` or `\ignorespaces` so as to support the traditional way of typing French.

```
\frlang
\fontfam[Times]


\begingroup
\catcode`\:=\active
\catcode`\;=\active
\catcode`\?=\active
\catcode`\!=\active 
\catcode`\«=\active 
\catcode`\»=\active 

\gdef\frenchpunct{%
  \catcode`\:=\active \def:{\unskip\thinspace\char`\: }
  \catcode`\;=\active \def;{\unskip\thinspace\char`\; }
  \catcode`\?=\active \def?{\unskip\thinspace\char`\? }
  \catcode`\!=\active \def!{\unskip\thinspace\char`\! }
  \catcode`\«=\active \def«{\char`\«\thinspace\ignorespaces}
  \catcode`\»=\active \def»{\unskip\thinspace\char`\» }
}
\endgroup
\def\nofrenchpunct{%
  \catcode`\:=12
  \catcode`\;=12
  \catcode`\?=12
  \catcode`\!=12
  \catcode`\«=12
  \catcode`\»=12 
}


\frenchpunct
bonjour: monde; oui? non! «aujourd'hui»

bonjour : monde ; oui ? non ! « aujourd'hui »

\nofrenchpunct

bonjour: monde; oui? non! «aujourd'hui»

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I was inverting the thin space. If you don't mind explaining succinctly: what is the difference between `\unskip` and `\ignorespaces`, and why is it advisable to use it here?

Comment: @user574859 A French typist would be used to type `Et voilà !` with a space before the exclamation mark, which `\unskip` will remove. Similarly, they would be used to type `« xyz »` so we want to ignore the possible space after the opening guillemet.

Comment: Shouldn't you test if the mode is math? It could cause issues with factorials for example

Comment: @John Assuming that the French wouldn't want a thin space also in that case, you should add.